# Clojure testing 'is' assertion not executing

Tags: testing, clojure

I have a program that takes input from stdin and writes its output to stdout. To test it, I am using `with-in-str` to pass it input and then binding *out* to a temporary file that is slurped and compared to the expected results. The file is successfully written to with this approach. However when I slurp the file for the `is` assertion, the assertion does not assert and any print **after** the slurp is not printed out.

```
(def test-case
  {
   :name  "input is less than batch size"
   :input ["a" "a"]
   :batch-size 3
  })

(deftest assertion-failing
  (testing "sample code of assertion failing to execute"
    (let [rand-file (str "/tmp/fl" (rand 10000))
          want      "{\"a\": true}"]
      (mock-and-run-test test-case rand-file)
      (println "before slurp")
      (is (= (slurp rand-file) want))
      (println "after slurp"))))
```

The output when this test is executed is:

```
bash-3.2$ lein test :only collection.core-test/assertion-failing

lein test collection.core-test
before slurp
bash-3.2$
```

**EDITED**
Here is the `mock-and-run-test` and its helper form, `run-t`:

```
(defn run-t
  [tt rand-file]
  (binding [*out* (clojure.java.io/writer rand-file)]
    (with-in-str
      (str/join "\n" (:input tt))
      (-main "-c" "users-query"))))

(defn mock-and-run-test
  [tt rand-file]
  (with-redefs
    [batch-size-map {"users-query" (:batch-size tt)}
     works-check  (fn [t] true)]
    (run-t tt rand-file)))
```

Comment: it would be easier to help you if you include a minimal `mock-and-run-test` that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @nberger, it's updated with the supporting forms. Please let me know if there is anything else that will help in the analysis.

Comment: There are still definitions missing: -main, batch-size-map. Please post a minimal example where the issue can be reproduced. Perhaps while preparing the example you find how to fix the issue. And if not, it will be much easier for the rest of us to help you.

Comment: A github repo that we can clone and just run `lein test` would be ideal.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, slurping works just fine with `binding` and `with-in-str`. There must be something wrong in the code not shown, probably in the main method? I don’t think you should create a GitHub repo for this, just post a minimal self-contained piece of code here.

Comment: I did what you recommended, @nberger, and kept breaking down the code into smaller and smaller pieces to get to a minimal reproducible source that I could share with you. In going through that process I found the culprit was a hidden call to `System/exit` in a separate thread after all processing had completed. Thank you for your time and assisting me in isolating the root cause!